# Search a list or array for best match to a sublist (by numerical difference)?

Tags: python, arrays, list, search, data-structures

I have a list of values like this:

```
[ 669,  592,  664, 1005,  699,  401,  646,  472,  598,  681, 1126, ...]
```

My question is, given a small list of numbers, such as:

```
[ 400, 650, 475 ]
```

how do I get a sublist that is closest to the sublist, for instance:

```
[401,  646,  472, ]  # difference = 1 + 4 + 3 = 8
```

I started looking at organizing all lengths of sublists in heap trees but then I realized I'm being ridiculous, surely someone has had this problem before, but I can't find anything. Do you think I'll need to do that?

Is there a way to search a list for the best sublist (consecutive) matching (or closest to) the search criteria?

Comment: "but then I realized I'm being ridiculous" LOL. I do that sometimes too.

Comment: I don't think it's necessarily ridiculous. Another option is to do a two pass approach. First pass just compute absolute difference of length `n` sublist to create a new list. Second pass you can go through the new list and find the smallest value. If you want multiple sublists you can use a dictionary.

Comment: You can use sum() and check the result. I will try to create someting here.

Comment: Do you definitely want just the best matching sublist? not necessarily a sorted list of sublists or the n best or something similar?

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper at first I thoguht getting a list of sublists would be good, but then I realized that getting a lists of sublists is really the same thing as getting the best match, removing it from the list then getting the best match again, and so on. So I changed the question to say just the best match because I think that would suffice. but I don't know...

Comment: How long are your lists, and does it need to be fast?

Comment: If you plan to repeatedly take the best match and remove you'll get better performance if you just sort once instead and iterate over the sorted list. If you just want n-best where n is more than a very small number but not the whole list it might be worth the hassle of using heapq (sorting can do that case fine too but does unnecessary work).

Comment: @HeapOverflow the lists could be millions of numbers long, but really all sizes, maybe just 1000 in some cases. fast is ideal. I had another thought for the large list case: maybe I could used vectorized calc to speed things up?

Comment: Too late for me @Legit. You already have some great answers.

Comment: If you need to do many queries on the same list, and the length of the sublists for each query is either the same or there is a known upper bound, you should consider pre-processing the list to put all of its sublists into some kind of spatial data structure which supports efficient nearest-point queries. The total absolute difference between the query list and a sublist is the Manhattan distance, so there are many known spatial/geometric data structures which are applicable to this problem.

Comment: @kaya3 my intuition exactly, but I have no upper bound on the length of the searchable list or search-item-list thus I'd have to make a heap tree or something for every possible size. which is why I thought, I'd ask the question on here. Perhaps if I find the general case falls within a particular range I can just do the optimization on that stuff. idk. I have some great answers below that should suffice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate over the sublists of the longer list and pass a key function into `min`:

```
lst = [ 669,  592,  664, 1005,  699,  401,  646,  472,  598,  681, 1126 ]
small = [ 400, 650, 475 ]
match = min((lst[i:i + len(small)] for i in range(len(lst) - len(small) + 1)), key=lambda sub: sum(abs(a - b) for a, b in zip(small, sub)))
print(match) # 401,  646,  472
```

And if you want a sorted list of best match to worst match, simply replace `min` with `sorted`.

```
print(sorted((lst[i:i + len(small)] for i in range(len(lst) - len(small) + 1)), key=lambda sub: sum(abs(a - b) for a, b in zip(small, sub))))
[[401, 646, 472], [472, 598, 681], [669, 592, 664], [646, 472, 598], [699, 401, 646], [1005, 699, 401], [592, 664, 1005], [664, 1005, 699], [598, 681, 1126]]
```

If you find one-liners scary (I must admit I do, haha), here's a slightly more readable version:

```
lst = [ 669,  592,  664, 1005,  699,  401,  646,  472,  598,  681, 1126 ]
small = [ 400, 650, 475 ]

def key(sublist):
    result = 0
    for a, b in zip(sublist, small):
        result += abs(a - b)
    return result

sublist_iter = (lst[i:i + len(small)] for i in range(len(lst) - len(small) + 1))
match = min(sublist_iter, key=key) # or `sorted`
print(match)
```

Comment: Personally I'd break it up a little, give the sublist iterator and maybe the score function names so it's a little clearer what's happening, but this is the answer I was in the middle of writing up as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
import operator
numbers = [ 669,  592,  664, 1005,  699,  401,  646,  472,  598,  681, 1126, 669,  592,  664]

search =  [ 400, 650, 475 ]

diffs = {}

for index in range(len(numbers)-len(search)+1):
    subset = numbers[index:index+len(search)]
    diff = sum([abs(x-y) for x,y in zip(subset,search)])
    diffs[diff] = diffs.get(diff,[]) + [subset]

for key, value in sorted(diffs.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(0)):
    print("{} : {}".format(key, value))
```

## Output:

```
8 : [[401, 646, 472]]
330 : [[472, 598, 681]]
516 : [[669, 592, 664], [669, 592, 664]]
547 : [[646, 472, 598]]
719 : [[699, 401, 646]]
728 : [[1005, 699, 401]]
736 : [[592, 664, 1005]]
843 : [[664, 1005, 699]]
862 : [[1126, 669, 592]]
880 : [[598, 681, 1126]]
951 : [[681, 1126, 669]]
```

It is printed in order and in case you have the same value twice it print both list for this difference.

Comment: You can get a minor optimization by using `operator.itemgetter(0)` as your `key` instead of a `lambda` - I remember it being about a 10% speedup when I last looked into it a few years back.

Comment: this looks like it's essentially the same as the answer provided by iz_ except your answer is more clear about whats going on. Am I right about that?

Comment: @LegitStack nearly the same. Before he edit he only had the best match that's why I submit mine as well. In my solution you have two advantages: You get the difference as a key and in case two list are equal (like in 516) you can see it in mine solution but not in that von iz_

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper thanks for the input. I remember that I read something but I forgot, I changed my solution.

Comment: Well, this builds an intermediate data structure (`diffs`) so it'll take more memory and do more work. If you have a use for the resulting dict of lists of lists, this is good, but if you just want the closest match or best n I'd stick with the other version. (`sort` docs say the key function is evaluated exactly once per element so you're not saving evaluations by keeping your own internal record of its value.)

Comment: It always depends on the use case :)

Answer (score 1):

Surprised no one offered a `numpy` solution:

```
import numpy as np

numbers = np.array([669, 592, 664, 1005, 699, 401, 646, 472, 598, 681, 1126])
searchs = [400, 650, 475]

for search in searchs:
    result = numbers[np.abs(numbers - search).argmin()]
    print(result)
```

Outputs:

```
401
646
472
```

Comment: wow, that's an easy implementation! so, do you think this is faster than the accepted answer (list comprehension approach)?

Comment: Let me run some tests. Curious myself, tbh.

Comment: Definitely faster; unfortunately, it seems incorrect. The closest numbers should be consecutive in the list, but this answer does not take this into account. It looks for a number closest to each element of the smaller list, and they just happen to be consecutive in this case.

Comment: @iz_ Why would the closest number be consecutive in the list? In the case of `650` in `searchs`, why wouldn't `649` in `numbers` be an appropriate return? Asking out curiosity- I didn't see OP specify.

Comment: he want the closest sublist. For example if you take `numbers = np.array([669, 592, 664, 1005, 699, 401, 646, 472, 598, 681, 1126,647])` the output would be `401 647 472` but that is not a valid sublist from the list (3 numbers next to each other) but rather the 3 smallest number from the list.

Comment: Not exactly sure what you are asking, but my understanding of the question is to look for a sublist in `numbers` (`len(searchs)` elements next to each other) that is most "similar" (smallest element-wise difference) to `searchs`. For instance, if you were to append `400` to `numbers`, your solution would print `400 646 472` (three numbers that aren't a sublist of `numbers`).

Comment: @Boendal Sublist, not subset. Subset would actually be what this does (or something similar)

Comment: Thank you Boendal, iz_, and Heap, you guys clarified my question -- I misunderstood at first!

Answer (score 1):

Fast NumPy solution:

```
import numpy as np

# Taken from https://rigtorp.se/2011/01/01/rolling-statistics-numpy.html
def rolling_window(a, window):
    shape = a.shape[:-1] + (a.shape[-1] - window + 1, window)
    strides = a.strides + (a.strides[-1],)
    return np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, shape=shape, strides=strides)

lst = np.array([669, 592, 664, 1005, 699, 401, 646, 472, 598, 681, 1126])
small = np.array([400, 650, 475])

sublists = rolling_window(lst, len(small))

# Only find the best match
match = sublists[np.abs(sublists - small).sum(axis=1).argmin()]
print(match)

# Array of matches, best to worst
match = sublists[np.abs(sublists - small).sum(axis=1).argsort()]
print(match)
```

Timings:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np
   ...:
   ...: # Taken from https://rigtorp.se/2011/01/01/rolling-statistics-numpy.html
   ...: def rolling_window(a, window):
   ...:     shape = a.shape[:-1] + (a.shape[-1] - window + 1, window)
   ...:     strides = a.strides + (a.strides[-1],)
   ...:     return np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, shape=shape, strides=strides)
   ...:
   ...: lst = np.array([669, 592, 664, 1005, 699, 401, 646, 472, 598, 681, 1126])
   ...: small = np.array([400, 650, 475])
   ...:
   ...: sublists = rolling_window(lst, len(small))

In [2]: %timeit sublists[np.abs(sublists - small).sum(axis=1).argmin()]
6.43 µs ± 51.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [3]: %timeit sublists[np.abs(sublists - small).sum(axis=1).argsort()]
10 µs ± 1.03 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [4]: lst = [ 669,  592,  664, 1005,  699,  401,  646,  472,  598,  681, 1126 ]
   ...: small = [ 400, 650, 475 ]

In [5]: %timeit min((lst[i:i + len(small)] for i in range(len(lst) - len(small) + 1)), key=lambda sub: sum(abs(a - b) for a, b in zip(small, sub)))
17.4 µs ± 1.39 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [6]: %timeit sorted((lst[i:i + len(small)] for i in range(len(lst) - len(small) + 1)), key=lambda sub: sum(abs(a - b) for a, b in zip(small, sub)))
15.9 µs ± 208 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

I expect speedups to be even greater if the lists are long.